# I am having trouble building a quasar project for Android

Tags: javascript, android, quasar

I wrote a small qr-code reader app on quasar, it was built successfully on xcode, but when I try to build an android project it fails with

```
error: resource style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless (aka org.cordova.quasar.app:style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless) not found.
```

I have tried everything but nothing seems to be working. I am using quasar 0.17

Comment: you have not import the library for Borderless Button in your gradle file